# How to test that Twitter-Bootstrap tab opens with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, capybara

I have a tab-panes by Twitter-Bootstrap on my page. How can I test with Capybara that getting the page like "/pages/1#some_tab" the "some_tab" tab-pane is opening?

Comment: For a related issue with poltergeist, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340038/phantomjs-not-waiting-for-full-page-load

Answer (score 1):

```
page.has_selector?('div', :text => 'something in my tab', :visible => true)
```

The key is adding the visible => true option.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work for me. My test passes both with "visible: true" and "visible: false" when there is required selector anywhere on page. I use this line to test: `page.should have_selector('a', text: "New task", visible: true)`