# How can I use jquery(window.load) in Casperjs

Tags: jquery, casperjs

### Here is my script

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   clientScripts: [
     '/Path/to/JQuery/Test/jquery-2.0.3.js'  
   ],
   logLevel: "info",             
   logLevel: "debug",
   verbose: true
});

casper.start("http://www.google.com", function(){
    console.log(this.evaluate((function() {
        $( window ).load(function(){
            return "======Page"+$('title').text()+"=========" ;
        });    
    })));  
});

casper.run();
```

### Result in console

```
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://www.google.com/ (HTTP 200)

null

[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected /Path/to/JQuery/Test/jquery-2.0.3.js client side
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected /Path/to/JQuery/Test/jquery-2.0.3.js client side
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 1154ms
```

My function returns a null value?
Help ?? Thanks

Comment: I'm similarly having a ton of trouble getting PhantomJS and CasperJS to wait for a full page load. I'm trying to follow this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472788/470749

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `$(window).load` but `document.readyState === "complete"`

```
casper.start("http://www.google.com", function(){
    this.echo(this.evaluate((function() {
        if(document.readyState === "complete") {
            return "======Page"+$('title').text()+"=========" ;
        }
    })));
});
```