# how to make headless browser stay on page so that all scripts can load

Tags: phantomjs, headless-browser

Hi I am new to headless browser testing/navigating and I was wondering if there was any way for PhantomJS to stay on the webpage for a while (maybe 1 sec) so that it has time for all scripts to load on the page.  Is there any way to do that in PhantomJS?  Any help would be appreciated. THanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phantomjs not waiting for "full" page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340038/phantomjs-not-waiting-for-full-page-load)

Comment: ^ This question has many great ways to solve this.