# PhantomJS 2.0.0 doesn't wait for page to load

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot

The script below contains some URLs in `links` array. The function `gatherLinks()` is used to gather more URLs from sitemap.xml of the URLs in `links` array. Once the `links` array has enough URLs (decided by variable `limit`), function `request()` is called for each URL in `links` array to send a request to the server, fetch the response and save the image using `page.render()` function.

The problem is that when I run it using PhantomJS 2.0.0, many of the images lack a lot of content, i.e. PhantomJS probably doesn't wait for all content to load. But when I use PhantomJS 1.9.8, all content is loaded just fine. What could be the reason?

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var links = [];

links = [
    "http://somesite.com",
    "http://someothersite.com",
       . 
       .
       .
 ];

var index = 0, fail = 0, limit = 20;
finalTime = Date.now();

var gatherLinks = function(link){
  var page = webpage.create();
  link = link + "/sitemap.xml";
  console.log("Fetching links from " + link);

  page.open(link, function(status){
    if(status != "success"){
      console.log("Sitemap Request FAILED, status: " + status);
      fail++;
      return;
    }

    var content = page.content;
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/xml');
    var loc = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('loc');

    for(var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++){
      if(links.length < limit){
        links[links.length] = loc[i].textContent;
      } else{
        console.log(links.length + " Links prepared. Starting requests.\n");
        index = 0;
        page.close();
        request();
        return;
      }
    }

    if(index >= links.length){
      index = 0;
      console.log(links.length + " Links prepared\n\n");
      page.close();
      request();
      return;
    }

    page.close();
    gatherLinks(links[++index]);
  });
};

var request = function(){
  t = Date.now();
  var page = webpage.create();
  page.open(links[index], function(status) {
    console.log('Loading link #' + (index + 1) + ': ' + links[index]);
    console.log("Time taken: " + (Date.now() - t) + " msecs");

    if(status != "success"){
      console.log("Request FAILED, status: " + status);
      fail++;
    }

    page.render("img_200_" + index + ".jpeg", {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
    if(index >= links.length-1){
      console.log("\n\nAll links done, final time taken: " + (Date.now() - finalTime) + " msecs");
      console.log("Requests sent: " + links.length + ", Failures: " + fail);
      console.log("Success ratio: " + ((links.length - fail)/links.length)*100 + "%");
      page.close();
      phantom.exit();
    }

    index++;
    page.close();
    request();
  });
}

gatherLinks(links[0]);
```

Comment: I'm similarly having a ton of trouble getting PhantomJS and CasperJS to wait for a full page load. I'm trying to follow this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472788/470749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJS doesn't define when in the page load process the `page.open` callback is called. So, there's nothing actually wrongly claimed.

It could be that you can add a static wait amount with `setTimeout()` which should help for dynamic sites. There are also approaches where you can see if there are pending requests by counting how many requests where sent with `page.onResourceRequested` and how many requests finished with `page.onResourceReceived`/`page.onResourceTimeout`/`page.onResourceError`.

If it is actually a PhantomJS bug, then there is not much can to besides try some of the command line switches.