# Cannot get link to be clicked and switch to next page using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am having an issue getting phantomJS to click the login button on a website.

I can see in my second screenshot that it is trying to select the login button, but I cannot get it to wait and take the screenshot on the next page.

Here is my JS file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {width: 1920,height: 1080};
page.open('http://clubs.bluesombrero.com/default.aspx?portalid=1809', function (status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);
    if (status === "success") {
        var url = page.url;
        console.log('URL: ' + url);
        console.log("TC0001: Pass");
        page.render('TC0001.png');

        var a = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('#dnn_dnnLOGIN_cmdLogin');
        });

        page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft, a.offsetTop);

        page.render('TC0002.png');
    } else {
        console.log("TC0001: Failed, Page did not load.");
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I have tried a few ways to get it to wait to take the screenshot after the page has loaded, but I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page.sendEvent()` is a synchronous function that finishes as soon as its action is done. The next call (`page.render()`) is executed even before the request which was triggered by the click is answered.

#### 1. `setTimeout`

JavaScript provides two functions to wait a static amount of time: `setTimeout` and `setInterval`:

```
page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft, a.offsetTop);

setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('TC0002.png');
    phantom.exit();
}, 5000);
```

(don't forget to remove the other `phantom.exit()` since you don't want to exit too early)

Of course the problem is now that on one hand the page still might not be ready after 5 seconds or on the other hand the page was loaded extremely fast and just sits there doing nothing.

#### 2. `waitFor`

A better approach would be to use the [`waitFor()` function](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) that is provided in the examples folder of PhantomJS. You can wait for a specific condition of the page like the existence of a specific element:

```
page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft, a.offsetTop);

waitFor(function _testFx(){
    return page.evaluate(function(){
        return !!document.querySelector("#someID");
    });
}, function _done(){
    page.render('TC0002.png');
    phantom.exit();
}, 10000);
```

#### 3. `page.onLoadFinished`

Another approach would be to listen to the `page.onLoadFinished` event which will be called when the next page is loaded, but you should register to it before you click:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(){
    page.render('TC0002.png');
    phantom.exit();
};

page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft, a.offsetTop);
```

#### 4. `page.onPageCreated`

Whenever a new window/tab would be opened in a desktop browser, the `page.onPageCreated` would be triggered in PhantomJS. It provides a reference to the newly created page, because the previous page is not overwritten.

```
page.onPageCreated = function(newPage){
    newPage.render('TC0002.png');
    newPage.close();

    phantom.exit();
};

page.sendEvent('click', a.offsetLeft, a.offsetTop);
```

In all the other cases, the `page` instance is overwritten by the new page.

#### 5. "Full" page load

That might still not be sufficient, because PhantomJS doesn't specify what it means when a page is loaded and the JavaScript of the page may still make further requests to build up the page. This Q&A has some good suggestions to wait for a "full" page load: [phantomjs not waiting for “full” page load](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11340038/1816580)

Comment: page.onLoad finished work's most of the time.  But on longer page loads it seems to continue on immaturely.  

With waitFor and setTimeout/setInterval My code seems to run multiple times.  I can't seem to figure out why

Comment: You could either set the timeout to some astronomical value or change the implementation of `waitFor` not disregard the timeout. Something like this: `function indefiniteWait(check, done) { setTimeout(function(){ if(check()) done() }, 250) }`. That's it.

Comment: How would one accomplish this when using phantom as a child process in node though?

Comment: @Carl91 If you use a PhantomJS as a child process then my answer applies 100%. Please be more specific what your issue is. I suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: I ser. As a matter of fact i did :) ucan fond it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861422/node-js-phantom-click-button

Comment: forgot to tag you @ArtjomB.