# Click and open a new page in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I know how to open a page and trigger event in `PhantomJS`:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open(url,status=>{
  page.evaluate(function() {
      var e = new MouseEvent("click",{...});
      document.querySelector("a.link").dispatchEvent(e);
    });
});
```

As shown, the `a.link` will be clicked, and a new page will be visited, while I wonder if I can evaluate the new page? For example, I want to make some action in the new opened page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Vaviloff:  Can you provide an example?

Comment: There are [more ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33868216/1816580) though.