# PhantomJS - content loaded from click event does not load to DOM

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I would like to test a click event on an anchor tag triggers the right DOM transformations.  What I see in the browser works and I've pretty much checked each line of my code returns what I want, except when I let PhantomJS do it, the expected DOM transformations don't seem to trigger.

Here is my code:

```
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {                     

        var specifications = page.evaluate(function() {
            var a = document.querySelector("a[href='#Specifications']");
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');

            e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);

            return document.querySelector("div#Specifications").innerHTML;              
        });

        console.log(specifications);
        phantom.exit()

    } else {
       phantom.exit(1);
    });
});
```

I initially just called `document.querySelector("a[href='#Specifications']").click();` with the same result.  In my web browser, clicking on that link triggers the DOM transformations.  I can't however reproduce it in PhantomJS.

Comment: already tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much time figuring out what is going on, here are some recommendations for people who run into a similar problem.

First, make sure your selectors are not the problem.  In my case I decided to stick with the document API.  Unlike what some people have said about sending click events, the following works fine:

```
document.querySelector("a[href='#some_section']").click();
```

You should be able to use jQuery with `page.includeJs()` too.

Make sure the page resources are being requested and received after you call `click()` by using `onResourceRequested` and `onResourceReceived` like this:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(data, request) {
    console.log("phantomJS: resource requested: " + data.url);
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    console.log("phantomJS: resource received: " + response.url);
};
```

Finally, make sure if you are evaluating some value that needs to be inserted after a click event that it is done after the resource is received.  What I ended up doing is:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var data = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('div#InsertDiv').innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(data);

    phantom.exit();
}, 2000);
```

Basically, if external resource is being requested, you have to set an asynchronous wait time for it.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21401636/1816580) should be helpful in removing that static wait with `setTimeout`