# Wait for some time in PhantomJS between console logs in the page context

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs

I need to wait some time in PhantomJS. I searched a lot but didn't find an answer. I try this code inside `page.open` but it doesn't work.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("works");
    clearInterval(interval); 
}, 3000);
```

I also tried `setTimeout` but it also didn't help

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("works");
}, 3000);
```

What is a solution for waiting some seconds?

I need to wait 3 seconds between logs: `jquery included` and `works`. But these logs appear in console simultaneously.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var url = "https://www.youtube.com";

page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status == "success"){
        console.log(status);
        if (page.injectJs("jquery.min.js")){
            console.log("jquery included");
            page.evaluate(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){       
                }, 3000);
            });
            console.log("works");
            phantom.exit();
        }       
    }
    else{
        console.log(status);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: what about `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`?

Comment: It can be duplicate, but I can't understand yet what should I do with `page.evaluate`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Are you trying to wait inside of the page context (inside `page.evaluate`) and wondering why nothing is printed to the console?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have a cycle. In it I click on a button and need to wait some time and then I reload page. In other words, I have two `console.log` and need to `setTimeout` between them

Comment: As for every question which seeks debugging help, what's your definition of *"it doesn't work"*? What do you see and what do you expect to see? Please be more specific. It also wouldn't hurt to show a bigger part of your script to rule out simple mistakes.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I modified topic with the whole code example.

Comment: @levshkatov you cannot `setTimeout` *between* them, but you can run your second `console.log` in the callback of the `setTimeout` which is effectively the same thing. If this is what youre truly wanting to do: `setTimeout(function() { console.log('works') }, 3000)` is what you want inside the `page.evaluate`

Comment: You exit phantom before the timeout callback ever executes. I think that's your problem. Move phantom.exit() to inside the setTimeout callback if you want to wait for a few seconds. setTimeout doesn't halt execution of the rest of the script.

Comment: @ginman I can't run console.log inside `page.evaluate`

Comment: @dannyjolie Also is for `phantom.exit()`. I can't run it inside `evaluate`.

Comment: @levshkatov I see that in the docs that console wont show, and you have no access to the `phantom` object. You can however run pretty much any other code inside of it. At this point, we would need to know what code you are really trying to run, as `setTimeout` is most likely the solution.
You can also add a listener to pipe the `console.log` messaging - see the last section in http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

Comment: Ah, that's true. It's been a while since I used PhantomJS :) Anyway, this should be what you're looking for, see answer 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340038/phantomjs-not-waiting-for-full-page-load

Comment: @ginman It also didn't help if I put `console.log` inside `setTimeout`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a collection of what is wrong:

- JavaScript has no sleep function like other languages, because it is single-threaded. This means that a sleep would effectively stop all other processing. So, you *cannot* use

  ```
  console.log("1");
  setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);
  console.log("2");
  ```

  and expect `2` to be printed 5 seconds after `1`. `2` will be printed immediately after `1`. You need to use the asynchronous nature of JavaScript:

  ```
  console.log("1");
  setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("2");
  }, 5000);
  ```
- `phantom.exit()` must be called when you're done with the script. This means that you need to call it from the `setTimeout` callback.
- `page.evaluate` is the sandboxed page context. You cannot use variables defined outside. As such, you cannot use `phantom.exit()` inside of `page.evaluate()`, but you can use the [`window.callPhantom`/`page.onCallback` pair](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html) to get a message from the page context.
- If you want to receive console messages from the page context, you need to provide a [`onConsoleMessage` event handler](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html).

#### Full script:

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var url = "https://www.youtube.com";

page.onCallback = function(data){
    if (data.type === "exit") {
        phantom.exit();
    }
};
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
    console.log("remote: " + msg);
};
page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status == "success"){
        console.log(status);
        if (page.injectJs("jquery.min.js")){
            console.log("jquery included");
            page.evaluate(function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log("works");
                    window.callPhantom({type: "exit"});
                }, 3000);
            });
        }       
    }
    else{
        console.log(status);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```