# Run a source's javascript using phantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, web-crawler

I want to do the following:

1. Go to a website
2. Click on a button => a javascript function will change parts of the html
3. Fetch some contents of the newly changed html

All these automatically

I tried several tools provided for nodejs including [node-cralwer](https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Currently, I have this code running in PhantomJS

```
page.open('https://www.thegioididong.com/dtdd/iphone-x-256gb', function (status) {
    console.log("Status: " + status);

    var a = page.evaluate(function () {

        document.getElementsByClassName("viewparameterfull")[0].click()

        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('parameterfull')[0].textContent)
        return document.getElementsByClassName('parameterfull')[0].textContent
    })
    phantom.exit();
})
```

and the output was

```
Status: success
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getFullSpec
```

Using Chrome Debugger, I can see that `getFullSpec` is a function that:

- Is fired when the button selected in the code is clicked
- Can be found on another `js` file that is downloaded when the page loads.

My questions are:

- When `PhantomJS` *opens* a link with `page.open()`, does it load every file (js, css...) like the browser does?
- If it does, how can I use `PhantomJS` to run that `getFullSpec` (which is contained in another `js` file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Js in eveluate method will be executed in page,
   and there is an error in onclick listener.

You can open a page, open devtools, search for code in js sources.

Comment: thanks for fast response! So you mean I can use PhantomJS to do this but I have error in my code? Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: It is error in page js file. I don't know how to fix, maybe getFullSpec is not initialized yet. So try to set delay before clicking.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if I get you right. If you mean the source's javascript has an error, I think that's not the case cause it works when I loaded it in Chrome.

Comment: Then you are doing a click before js.file which contains getFullSpec() is loaded. I don't know full phantom api, but try to eveluate you script, when all page js are loaded. 
Here is similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340038/phantomjs-not-waiting-for-full-page-load.

Comment: I have found the solution after many trials and errors with asynchronous functions. The problem seems to be what you said - I click before the javascript file was loaded. If you could, please write your answer in a separate post so I can mark it as the answer!

Comment: We came to proper solution in this post, so seems it must be the answer. I can edit it, but seems it is not needed.